# Uploading image to WCF Api with RestSharp - Image not valid

Tags: c#, rest, azure, restsharp

I have successfully made an app that sends a request from my Windows Phone to a WCF api hosted in an azure web role. I am using a restful POST method to do this using RestSharp. It all works brilliantly and the images are appearing in storage but the images are not opening as normal image files.

Comparing them to other images I uploaded previously, in the metadata info it says the unviewable images have a contentMD5 field which is set to something like "AKEYWqGgulwi6/9/VY2KPg==" (whereas the others do not) could this be what is causing the problem with the files?

I have attached my RestSharp code, maybe I'm am adding something I shouldn't be? The error I suspect must be coming from here as this is the only place where the imagestream is manipulated.

```
   public void SendRequest(Stream imageStream, string imageID)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = apiAddress;
        var request = new RestRequest("agerecog/{imageName}", Method.POST);
        request.AddUrlSegment("imageName", imageID);

        //convert imagestream to byte array
        var byteArray = new byte[imageStream.Length];
        imageStream.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);

        //add byteArray to request
        request.AddFile("image/jpeg", byteArray, imageID);
        var url = client.BuildUri(request).ToString();
        client.ExecuteAsync<VizageResponse>(request, response =>
            {
                //request info. to be added here
            });
    }
```

**EDIT #1**
After some work I decided to change the addFile line to this:

```
  request.AddFile(null, byteArray, null);
```

Which changed the stream length and also made the contentMD5 field empty. However, the image is still not a valid image file. Given the fact the images I am comparing are both from the Windows Phone emulator they should both be an identical white page with a small black square in the corner - but there is a different in size between the file (5670 length for the valid image file, 6076 length for the original code and 6239 length using the second addFile above)

**EDIT #2**
Doing some more analysis, when the before the image Stream is sent its length property is 6116, when it arrives on the server, however it is 6370. 264 is being added from somewhere in the RestSharp method I believe or when the stream of data is interpreted on the server side. The code of the WCF service:

```
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/agerecog/{imageName}", Method = "POST")]
    VizageResult analyseFace(string imageName, Stream imageStream);
```

Comment: Can you compare the requests with Fiddler? You might also want the AddFile overload where you write directly to the stream.

Comment: Thanks John, I can't use fiddler unfortunately as the azure service is hosted in my local dev environment. I have however done a bit of investigate work which I will add to an edit above. I will writing directly to stream as well

Comment: directly to stream did not appear to work either unfortunately

Comment: I think it is working however I need to parse the file stream at the other end which I am currently not doing - this would explain the extra data in the stream I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

I have finally solved the problem and an image is visible as the end result. What was happening was that the imageStream also contained data regarding the name of the file and this was causing it (when saved in Azure) to not appear as an image file.

I fixed this by using the MultipartParser class found here: http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/ on the server side to parse the request into the filename  and filestream chunks. I then saved the image from this byte[] using the normal process.

My code to parse the webrequest data into its constituent parts is found below:

```
    MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();

     MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(dataStream);
        if (parser != null && parser.Success)
        {
            imageName = parser.Filename;
            imageStream.Write(parser.FileContents, 0, parser.FileContents.Length);
        }
```

When you use the memory stream remember to set its position back to 0 -  a schoolboy mistake I made!

Comment: But what should I do, if I have 3rd party web-service on linux-machine?! I think it's still restSahrp bug. Does somebody knows how to fix HTTP-body just the moment before the request sending???

Comment: Apologies for not replying - no idea unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I don’t very familiar RestSharp. Can you make sure the MD5 is correct? Try to compare the data in blob with the data in the original image file. Check, for example, whether they have the same size, whether the first/last several bytes are identical (and assume bytes in the middle are also identical).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and do that now. I have made an edit above. Going to try and few more things to find the route cause of the problem